# How to disable only long press gesture on UIWebView in iOS not using javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I am a having major crisis on this for almost 3 weeks...
I spent a lot of time on google, found out that even I disable long press gesture(LPG) on view, webview itself has its own gesture, so it doesnt work. (I checked it with setting LPG duration as 0.3, it catched LPG but as 0.4, copy menu pops up before it detects)
Also my url has iframe, thats why it doesnt take codes for javascript.

Here is how i did

1. `view > webview` (webview is located in the view(mycontroller))
2. I need to disable LPG on contents in an iframe
3. I need to disable for c`opy/paste/cut/delete` and also `hyperlink`
4. should be workd in iOS 5.0+

Im asking for

1. is there any way to disable webview's own gesture?
2. is there any way to apply javascript on iframe?
3. or is there other way to disable LPG on webview?

Please help me out guys!!!

Comment: make userinteraction false on webview

Comment: I need to disable long press gesture only. What you are telling is disabling all gestures which is not what I want.

Comment: I solved this problem. As I said earlier, the javascript goes on wrong frame so it didnt work properly. I asked web-developer to add it on proper location so it solved easily.